# How can I select the entire import statements using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I'm writing a static code analysis tool in Python.

Here's a sample of a code that needs to be analyzed:

```
import {
    component$,
    useClientEffect$,
} from '@builder.io/qwik'
 import Swiper from 'swiper'
import {
    Navigation,
    Pagination
} from 'swiper'
import { Image } from 'Base'
import Button from '../Shared/Button'
import Heading from '../Shared/Heading'
const Portfolio = component$(
    (
        {
            items,
            title,
            linkText,
            link
        }
    ) => {
```

One item that I have to check is to ensure that there is an empty line after the last import. As you can see in the example above, the `const Portfolio` which is the component declaration is attached to the previous import. I need to make sure it has an empty line before it.

I tried `(?<=import).*(?=from)`, but it does not work. Please note that a developer might place an empty line before two imports. Or he might place empty space before an import. In other words, a developer might write the most unformatted code.

What regular expression can I use to ensure this requirement?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you would have to do this using regular expressions? Regular expressions would be more difficult to write, more difficult to read, and slower to execute than pure python code.

Comment: No there is no reason at all. How this is simpler in Python? I'm totally OK to write just Python code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with so far:

`"(^[\s\n]{0,}import.*from[^a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ./a-zA-Z0-9']+$)|(^[\s]{0,}import.*(\n +.*|\s)*.*from[^a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ./a-zA-Z'0-9]+$)"mg`

There are 2 groups:

- `(^[\s\n]{0,}import.*from[^a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ./a-zA-Z0-9']+$)`

  - `^[\s\n]{0,}import` - a line starts with the word **import**. And before this word we can meet (or not at all) spaces, new lines.
  - `import.*from` between the words **import** and **from** we can meet anything
  - `from[^a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ./a-zA-Z0-9']+$` - the word **from** is followed by non-letter & non-digit symbols (`[^a-zA-Z0-9]+`) or letters/digits/single quote/dot/space (`[ ./a-zA-Z0-9']+`).
- `(^[\s]{0,}import.*(\n +.*|\s)*.*from[^a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ./a-zA-Z'0-9]+$)`

  - `^[\s]{0,}import` - a line starts with the word **import**. And before this word we can meet (or not at all) some spaces.
  - `import.*(\n +.*|\s)*.*from` - between the words **import** and **from** we can meet any text on multiple lines (here is why we need the flag `m` - multiline)
  - `from[^a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ./a-zA-Z0-9']+$` - *the same meaning as in the first group*

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2DcVnV/1)